# decimal points omitted in typecasting heavy program

Tags: c, floating-point, int, printf

I have written this code for gauss elimination method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float arr[3][4]={{0}}, i, j, k, p;
    printf("Enter the coefficients:-\n");
    for(i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("Row #(%d)\n", (int)(i+1));
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            scanf("%f", &arr[(int)i][(int)j]);
        }
    }
    for(k=1, p=(k-1); (k<=2); k++, p++)
    {
        for(i=k; i<=2; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<=3; j++)
            {
                arr[(int)i][(int)j]-=((arr[(int)i][(int)p]/arr[(int)p][(int)p])*arr[(int)p][(int)j]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            printf("%0.3f  ", arr[(int)i][(int)j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, it does not print the correct output values. An analysis of the output suggests the values have been rounded off or something. Im guessing somewhere the integer values of the 2-d array have been considered even though i have taken the array as double and only used typecasting for the syntax-valid element address. You can try this yourself by taking the matrix:

```
R1-   10  -1  2  4
R2-   1   10 -1  3
R3-   2   3  20  7
```

The correct output should be:

```
R1-   10    -1        2         4
R2-   0    10.1     -1.2       2.6
R3-   0     0       19.980    5.376
```

I am using the GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: why declare i, j, k and p as floats then cast them to ints everywhere? Do you have some vendetta against declaring them as ints?

Comment: I have tried declaring them as ints and they still give a rounded value. Help.

Comment: Is your algorithm even modifying what you think it is? Running your program results in the 1,2,3 triangle bottom left being zerod out - that is all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely not to do with rounding (the indices you pass into the array should not affect any rounding in the array itself).

I added a print statement in the main loop just to see what coefficients are being used when doing the per-row subtraction, and they appear to be different between each column, so it's likely your math that is off. I suspect it has to do with your `p` variable, which is always fixed to be the row above `k`, which I don't think will help you.

You want to get the row coefficient for each pair of rows and then subtract the row you're using to eliminate multiplied by that coefficient. The coefficient is `M(1,0)/M(0,0)` for the second-row-by-first-row elimination, `M(2,1)/M(1,1)` for the third-row-by-second-row elimination, and in general, `M(I,K)/M(K,K)` (where K is the row being used to eliminate, and I is the row you're eliminating from).

Ultimately you want to do:

```
For each row K excluding the last row (0 to 1)...
    For each row I after it (K+1 to 2)...
        Get the row factor = M(I, K) / M(K, K).
        For each column J (0 to 3)...
            M(I, J) -= M(K, J) * factor
```

Translate that (almost directly) into code, and it should come out as:

```
10.000000  -1.000000  2.000000   4.000000
-0.000000  10.100000  -1.200000  2.600000
-0.000000  -0.000000  19.980198  5.376237
```

Comment: I do not favor giving outright code for what appears to be a homework problem.

Comment: Good point, I (perhaps naively) didn't consider that. I've edited out the final solution, but I don't expect it'll be hard to draw it from the pseudo-code.

Comment: Come on now, clearly my question isnt a homework problem. I mean im not asking you to do my homework. I am merely asking you if there is some conversion problem inherent in the programming language. It just so happens that the problem is in the logic. How then can you point this out as a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare all the variables you use for array indices with an integer type.
2. Get rid of all the casts. You do not need any of them.
3. Replace all the constants for row and columns numbers with `Rows` and `Columns`, which you define just once.
4. Be consistent in your loop bounds; do not use `j < 4` in some places and `j <= 3` in others. (Both will become `j < Columns`.)
5. Get rid of `p`.
6. The loop on `k` iterates on the source rows, that is, the rows that contain data you will use to cancel other elements. It runs `for (k = 0; k < Rows-1; ++k)`.
7. The loop in `i` iterates the destination rows that you cancel for each `k`. It runs `for (i = k+1; i < Rows; ++i)`.
8. The factor you are going to use while canceling is the ratio between the element in column `k` of rows `i` and `k`. Calculate it once and call it `factor`.
9. For each column in row `i`, subtract from the element there `factor` times the element in the same column in row `k`.

I wrote code as described above, and it prints the results you say are expected.